# How do I add a Label inside another Label using classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am intended to make one class use another class as widget, for example: a Label A, within this will be Label B, but apparently no object can be used as an attribute

```
AttributeError: 'Label_A' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

code that I am trying to use:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")
win.geometry("640x480")

class Label_A(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # make a Label
        def label_a():
            self.label_a = tk.Label(self.parent, text="LABEL A", bg="red", fg="white", font=("Arial", 20), width=300, height=300)
            self.label_a.place(x=0, y=0)

        label_a()


class Label_B(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # make a Label
        def label_b():
            self.label_b = tk.Label(self.parent, text="LABEL B", bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Arial", 20), width=200, height=200)
            self.label_b.place(x=0, y=0)

        label_b()


Label_B(Label_A(win))

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use derived class of `tkinter.Frame`, so it can be frame in frame.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Frame_A(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.place(x=0, y=0, width=300, height=200)
        self.label_a = self.label()

    def label(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="LABEL A", bg="red", fg="white", font=("Arial", 20))
        label.place(x=0, y=0, width=300, height=200)
        return label

class Frame_B(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.place(x=0, y=0, width=200, height=100)
        self.label_b = self.label()

    def label(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="LABEL B", bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Arial", 20))
        label.place(x=0, y=0, width=200, height=100)
        return label


win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Test")
win.geometry("400x300")
Frame_B(Frame_A(win))
win.mainloop()
```

[image]